# Implementing a ListView with a CollectionViewSource - Not Refreshing?

Tags: c#, listview, microsoft-metro, collectionviewsource

I'm working on setting up a ListView whose `Source` property is set to an ivar of a class of mine, called `Cat`.

Each `Cat` has an `ObservableCollection` of `Trait` objects:

```
private ObservableCollection<Trait> _traits = new ObservableCollection<Trait>();

public ObservableCollection<Trait> Traits
{
get
    {
        return _traits;
    }
}

public void AddTrait(Trait t)
{
    _traits.Add(t);
    // Is this redundant? Is one better than the other?
    this.OnPropertyChanged("_traits");
    this.OnPropertyChanged("Traits");
}

public IEnumerator<Object> GetEnumerator()
{
    return _traits.GetEnumerator();
}
```

And then I'm assigning the `Source` property to this `Traits` collection:

```
this.CollectionViewSource.Source = CurrentCat.Traits;
```

This works properly, and the `Trait` objects are properly displayed in my `ListView`.

**The issue** is that changes to this underlying `_traits` collection do not cause the UI to update properly. For example, this:

```
void AddTraitButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (this.CurrentCat != null)
    {
        this.CurrentCat.AddTrait(new Trait());
    }
}
```

Doesn't seem to have any effect *immediately* in the UI, but if I reset the `Source` property like so:

```
var oldSource = this.CollectionViewSource.Source;
this.CollectionViewSource.Source = null;
this.CollectionViewSource.Source = oldSource;
```

Then the `ListView` updates properly. But, I'm sure there must be something that I'm missing, as I'd like for the UI to update upon the addition/removal of an item.

**Edit:** The `CollectionViewSource` is being applied to the `ListView` in my XAML file:

```
<CollectionViewSource x:Name="CollectionViewSource" x:Key="CollectionViewSource" />

...

<ListView x:Name="ItemListView" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource CollectionViewSource}}" ...
```

Comment: How is the CollectionViewSource being set to the ListView?

Comment: @craig Regarding the "Is this redundant? Is one better than the other?" comment: `_traits` is a private member and does not need to be passed to `OnPropertyChanged` - after all, there couldn't be anything bound to it to receive the update notification. `OnPropertyChanged("Traits");` will suffice.

Comment: @djacobson Thanks, that helps clarify things.

Comment: this.OnPropertyChanged("Traits"); Use this on your commented line about which is better, and only if when you do a binding it looks like {Binding Traits} and the bound object's DataContext is set to the object with the Traits property.

Answer (score 0):

I can't seem to find it now, but I seem to remember some problem with binding to `CollectionViewSource`. Have you tried binding directly to `CurrentCat.Traits` and setting `this.DataContext = this` in the code-behind (I am assuming you aren't using MVVM here)?

```
<ListView x:Name="ItemListView" ItemsSource="{Binding CurrentCat.Traits}" />
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I still haven't been able to successfully connect the dots. I'm not using MVVM to my knowledge, I'm very new to C# and WPF. From the code I've posted, and the other examples of MVVM I've seen, I'm fairly confident I'm doing something else. :)

Comment: Set the binding exactly as I posted it, and set `this.DataContext = this` in your code-behind's load section. See if that works.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than binding to the CollectionViewSource directly and replacing its `Source` to force a refresh, I believe you want to bind to the CVS's `View` property...

```xml
<ListView x:Name="ItemListView" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource CollectionViewSource}, Path=View}" ...
```

...and call `CollectionViewSource.Refresh()` after updating the source collection.

```
void AddTraitButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (this.CurrentCat != null)
    {
        this.CurrentCat.AddTrait(new Trait());
        this.CollectionViewSource.Refresh();
    }
}
```

Also, a couple notes, since you seem relatively new to .NET/WPF conventions:

- The private members of .NET classes are typically referred to as "fields" rather than "ivars" (Objective-C background? :))
- Prefixing class members with the `this` keyword is usually redundant, unless there is another identifier in scope with the same name
- It's worth exploring the [MVVM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx) and related patterns if you'll be doing anything non-trivial in WPF; they help you keep your views (XAML objects) as light and easy-to-change as possible.

  In your case, for example, I assume the code you've shown is from the code-behind of whatever Window or UserControl contains your ListView. Following the MVVM pattern would involve creating a separate "ViewModel" class that would contain the `Traits` collection and expose it via a `CollectionViewSource` (using the View property, as I've mentioned). Your UserControl would then have an instance of the ViewModel assigned as its [`DataContext`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.datacontext.aspx), and the ListView could be bound to the exposed CollectionView.

Comment: Strangely, the `View` property of my `CollectionViewSource` does not have a `Refresh()` method

Comment: That *is* strange, as the `CollectionViewSource.View` property is of type `ICollectionView`, which [does indeed have a Refresh() method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.icollectionview.aspx)... If you debug and break in that Click event, how is `this.CollectionViewSource`'s View property defined?

Comment: I have a similar problem with a CollectionViewSource that refuses to update like it's supposed to, and this answer causes a null refrence exception, because the CollectionViewSource's View property is always null.

Answer (score 0):

**You may work exclusively with the ObservableCollection still.** Although there is one problem - it would not show the data in IsInDesignMode. Maybe in the future it will improve.

```
public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
...
    private ObservableCollection<PartViewModel> _parts;
    public ObservableCollection<PartViewModel> Parts
    {
        get
        {
            if (_parts == null)
            {
                _parts = new ObservableCollection<PartViewModel>();
                _parts.CollectionChanged += _parts_CollectionChanged;
            }
            return _parts;
        }
    }

    object m_ReorderItem;
    int m_ReorderIndexFrom;
    void _parts_CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.Action)
        {
            case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove:
                m_ReorderItem = e.OldItems[0];
                m_ReorderIndexFrom = e.OldStartingIndex;
                break;
            case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add:
                if (m_ReorderItem == null)
                    return;
                var _ReorderIndexTo = e.NewStartingIndex;
                m_ReorderItem = null;
                break;
        }
    }

    private PartViewModel _selectedItem;
    public PartViewModel SelectedItem
    {
        get
        {
            return _selectedItem;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_selectedItem != value)
            {
                _selectedItem = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedItem");
            }
        }
    }
   ...

    #region ViewModelBase

    public override void Cleanup()
    {
        if (_parts != null)
        {
            _parts.CollectionChanged -= _parts_CollectionChanged;
        }
        base.Cleanup();
    }

    #endregion

  }

<Grid Background="{StaticResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Grid.Resources>
        <CollectionViewSource x:Name="PartsCollection" Source="{Binding Parts}"/>
    </Grid.Resources>

    <ListView Margin="20" CanReorderItems="True" CanDragItems="True" AllowDrop="True" 
              ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource PartsCollection}}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}" SelectionMode="Single">
        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"></Setter>
            </Style>
        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        ...
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```